# Importing lodash in React error (directory description file): SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Tags: reactjs

when `import _ from 'lodash'` in my App.js file, I get error

```
Error in ./src/App.js
Module not found: Syntax/Users/<PATH>/waveexchangeNode/package.json (directory description file): SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
```

this is a snippet of my package json (stackoverflow wont let me post the rest)

```
{
  "name": "waveexchange",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "0.7.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.0",
    "web3": "^0.17.0-beta",
    "lodash": "^4.17.2",
    "fixed-data-table": "^0.6.3",
    "react-hot-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.6",
    "ethereumjs-util": "^ 4.5.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "./node_modules/react-scripts/config/eslint.js"
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't believe the snippet will be sufficient. It's either malformed JSON in your package.json (http://jsonlint.com/) or something else we can't see w/o further details.

Comment: shoot! was malformed...the number of times a comma has stymied me...thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error indicates a malformed `package.json`.

Check JSON validity at sites like [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com) or via editor/IDE plugins.